# ¿Cómo graficar sin tomar en cuenta los "0"?

Tags: python

tengo una duda y como apenas soy nuevo con python quisiera su ayuda

Tengo mi base de datos de un excel, en promedio los valores están entre 39 mil y 40 mil, pero hay celdas vacías cuando no hay datos y cuando los gráfico me los toma como "0", ¿Cómo evitar que tome los espacios vacíos como ceros y solo tome los valores entre el intervalo?

Muchas gracias
Saludos

```
from itertools import cycle
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#cargamos el xlsx en memoria
wb = load_workbook('datos.xlsx', data_only=True)
#cargamos la hoja
sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja2')

#creamos dos arreglos en numpy para guardar las 'x' y las 'y'
matriz = np.zeros((sheet1.max_row, sheet1.max_column))

#leemos la hoja columna por columna y vamos guardando los valores 'x' e 'y'
for i in range(1,sheet1.max_row):
    for j in range(0,sheet1.max_column):
        matriz[i,j]=sheet1.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value

#creamos el grafico
colors = cycle(["aqua", "black", "blue", "fuchsia", "gray", "green", "lime", "maroon", "navy", "olive", "purple", "red", "silver", "teal", "yellow"])
plt.xlabel('día')
plt.ylabel('nT')
for y in range(1, sheet1.max_column):
    plt.plot(matriz[:,0],matriz[:,y], label=sheet1.cell(row=1,    column=y+1).value,color=next(colors))
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(0,456)
plt.ylim(39000,40000)
plt.title('Grafica nT')
plt.show()
´´´
```

Answer (score 1):

Las celdas vacías quedarán como valores `NaN` en el array de NumPy, ten en cuenta que una celda vacía no es lo mismo que una celda con un cero como valor, estas ultimas si producirían un cero en el array.

Si solo quieres que esos puntos se ignoren al graficar (sin interpolar valores) puedes simplemente aplicar un filtro boleano usando `numpy.isnan`:

```
for y in range(1, sheet1.max_column):
    not_nan_filter = ~np.isnan(matriz[:, y])
    plt.plot(
        matriz[not_nan_filter, 0],
        matriz[not_nan_filter, y],
        label=sheet1.cell(row=1, column=y+1).value,
        color=next(colors)
        )
```

Si todas las celdas de la fila estuvieran vacías entonces podrías simplemente eliminar esas filas del array.